# CSS Not locating images for sub indicators

Tags: css, superfish

http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/

I have a sub indicator on my menu which is located in images/arrows-ffffff.png for example.... Ive even tried pointing to the full URL, however its not displaying the sub indicators...

Any ideas?

My code is below:-

```
.sf-sub-indicator {
position:       absolute;
display:        block;
right:          .75em;
top:            1.05em; /* IE6 only */
width:          10px;
height:         10px;
text-indent:    -999em;
overflow:       hidden;
background:     url('images/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
```

thanks guys 
Kirsty

Comment: Hi @Kirsty Harris. You have a conflict in your JavaScript that is preventing jQuery from being recognised. It's possible this is preventing Superfish from working correctly.

Comment: Hi Kim3er... i have appeared to remove this (it was the extra call in the header) however its still not reconising the sub indicators :S

Comment: Try moving the doc ready script down below where you reference the jQuery library. It's saying jQuery is not defined.

Comment: Hi Hollister, i removed this just a second ago and its still not reconising the sub indicators and that my menu has a child theme :S

Comment: Now the error is `TypeError: $m(".ccf-datepicker").datepicker is not a function`

Comment: see thats a js in another theme lol!!!... fml...

Comment: ok, i removed that plug in... and still no indicators lol

Comment: You *removed* the doc ready handler, not *moved* it. Put it back in after all the other scripts. This would be a lot easier if you created a jsfiddle to isolate this issue.

Comment: so the load the script thing? ok i will try this. See the other scripts are in the functions.php file!?!

Comment: sorry Hollister im not savvy with that  :S

Comment: ok added it in again and it came up with the same error :S... ive loaded the scripts in the functions.php under a wp_enqueue_script function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19834/discussion-between-hollister-and-kirsty-harris)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ The problem was that you didn't fix the script, so the elements with the `sub-indicator` class didn't exist.

2/ Just change:

```
url('images/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px
```

To:

```
url('/images/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px
```

Use absolute paths. They're usually more reliable, especially in CSS files. Google for "relative vs absolute paths in css" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use `images/arrows-ffffff.png` it means your images folder and css file should be at same location but on observing your site, you are importing css file from `css/superfish.css`.
 so either move your css file to same folder OR
use one of these paths:

1. `http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/images/arrows-ffffff.png`
2. `../images/arrows-ffffff.png`

Comment: Hi Zaheer, surely this shouldnt matter as long as you use the correct path to the images? As in the superfish menu they are in a separate folder to the css!?

Answer (score -2):

Remove code:

```
overflow:       hidden;
```

Comment: haha sorry is that as I have a code in jsfiddle because I'm just giving my opinion in general and the overflow: hidden.